# How to highlight references instead of boxes in LyX?

Tags: hyperref, lyx

How can I replace boxes around references and highlighting them instead in LyX?

Something like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be using a document that is using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). The default presentation of links is to be boxed (in red). To change this, check the "Color links" option in Document > Settings... > PDF properties > Hyperlinks:

[image]

This will change your hyperlinks from

[image]

to

[image]

You can add other options too, as needed (like specific colours for specific types of links (like `linkcolor=blue`, say, so blue internal document links). See section **3.5 Extension options** of the [`hyperref` documentation](http://ctan.mirror.colo-serv.net/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-90003.5) for a list of colours you can specify, including their respective [defaults]:

- `linkcolor` [`red`]
  Colour for normal internal links.
- `anchorcolor` [`black`]
  Colour for anchor text.
- `citecolor` [`green`]
  Colour for bibliographical citations in text.
- `filecolor` [`cyan`]
  Colour for URLs which open local files.
- `menucolor` [`red`]
  Colour for Acrobat menu items.
- `runcolor` [`filecolor`]
  Colour for run links (launch annotations).
- `urlcolor` [`magenta`]
  Colour for linked URLs.
- `allcolors`
  Set all colour options (without border and field options).